# How do I split an RTF document into individual pages using PHP

Tags: php, rtf, documents

I have an RTF document that serves as a template for input data from a web page.  I need to know how to break the base template into individual pages for display on the website.  Is there a way to do this using PHP?  I have tried searching through the RTF code inside the document, but cannot find anything that gives me a good breaking point.  If anyone has a code snipit or and idea of how to do this I would be forever greatful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no explicit page breaks in RTF files, unless the user put them there.  "Paging" is computed when the document is rendered.  No easy answer it seems, IIUC.

Answer (score 1):

The RTF specification denotes \page as the command for a page break, but it seems to be ignored by most viewers. Google docs, for example, doesn't produce an RTF with page breaks when saving a document that contains page breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<br style=”page-break-before  :always” />` to where you want to end the page.

Example:

```
$string = 'This is page 1';
$string .= '<br style="page-break-before  :always" />';
$string .= 'This is page 2';
$string .= '<br style="page-break-before  :always" />';
```

More details at http://www.webdev-tuts.com/create-an-rtf-file-and-add-page-break-using-php.html